# Screen problem when playing Planetside 2 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, graphics, games, crossover

Recently started using Crossover and installed Planetside 2. I have tried to install Planeside 2 in steam and as a standalone from steam but i keep running into the same graphical problem.

Each time I start the game the menu and the game it self is red, everything is red except a few menu items and HUD items.

[image]

Here are more images of what I am talking about.

[more images](http://postimg.org/gallery/83o2oa6u/)

Answer (score 2):

I read my wine log files and they mentioned this line on game startup.

`err:winediag:wined3d_texture_init The application tried to create a DXTn texture, but the driver does not support them.`

A bit of searching led me to believe that WINE couldn't find any handler for the S3TC (aka DXTn) format, used for texture compression. It's a nonfree algorithm, so Mesa doesn't have support for it by default. You can enable support by installing the S2TC package.

`sudo apt-get install libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0`

You may need to get the 32-bit version of that package. I'm not sure which program's bittage dictates this: Planetside 2, or WINE.

`sudo apt-get install libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386`

Nothing will break if you have both.